# Registry entry for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: windows, windows-registry, sql-server

How can I check from the registry which Microsoft SQL Server(2000,2005 or 2008) is installed in my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` you should see subkeys in the left side pertaining to installed versions of SQL Server. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I cant see the registry enties you wanted to show. Can u please edit it...I wanted to check it with my entries

Comment: Inside there should be a version key which will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using the Registry, and use `SELECT @@VERSION` from a SQL query.

In the Registry, under HKLM\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server there are some keys and entries in there, but not as helpful as `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Comment: Agreed but actually I want to know it from a Registry only...I got it...in HKLM\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\Setup, entry called Version is what I was looking for.